# Can I extend macbook screen to windows laptop screen?

Tags: windows, windows-10, macos, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have a macbook 13 inch from early 2015 with macOS Mojave version 10.14.5, and a surface pro 4 with windows 10 pro version 1903, that I would link together as one screen. Is there a way to do this. I tried looking online, but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Connect from your Windows machine to your MAC using one of the remote connection products. Now view  your Windows apps in one half the screen, and your MAC apps in the other half. I can do this Windows to Windows using Radmin Server (Famatech)

Answer (score 2):

Synergy is an application that you install on multiple computers, usually one next to the other.  You can move the mouse continuously across them, one monitor to the next, as if it's one desktop.  https://symless.com/synergy

I've used it in the past, and it's neat as long as you never move those machines or have to do maintenance.  It's a bit of a hassle in real use.  Remote desktopping is usually easier.